How to include "regular occurrences" when exporting from an Outlook calendar
I export an Outlook calendar from a shared account to a CSV file which is incorporated into an Excel dashboard.
I want to set up a macro that automatically carries out this export on a daily or weekly basis.
I started by trying to get code that just carries out the export.
With the help of MS copilot, I managed to get VBA code which exports a CSV file.
It seems to only populate the calendar from 2012 for a couple of years. There are inputs from the last couple of years, but not the full daily calendar as it usually exports through the import/ export wizard.
I notice that when done manually, you are prompted about date ranges and recurring instances being incompatible with CSV. Is this something that cannot be done without the wizard compiling it?
I edited it to only export the current year from the calendar.
The CSV file had only five rows, which when carried out through the export wizard has the full daily calendar and a subject on each day.
Sub ExportSpecificCalendarToCSV()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim csvFile As String
    Dim output As String
    Dim calendarName As String
    Dim emailAddress As String
    Dim currentYear As Integer
    
    ' Initialize Outlook application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Specify the calendar name and email address
    calendarName = "On Call Engineer" ' Change this to the name of your calendar
    emailAddress = "*** Email address is removed for privacy ***,uk" ' Change this to your email address

    ' Get the specific calendar folder
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olFolder = olNamespace.Folders(emailAddress).Folders("Calendar").Folders(calendarName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Check if the folder exists
    If olFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Calendar not found!", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If 
    
    Set olItems = olFolder.Items
    
    ' Sort items by start date
    olItems.Sort "[Start]"

    ' Set the CSV file path
    csvFile = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Exam dates on shift\ OUTLOOK calendar.csv"

    ' Create CSV header
    output = "Subject,Start Date,Start Time,End Date,End Time,Location,Body" & vbCrLf

    ' Get the current year
    currentYear = Year(Date)
    
    ' Loop through calendar items
    For Each olItem In olItems
        If TypeName(olItem) = "AppointmentItem" Then
            If Year(olItem.Start) = currentYear Then   
                output = output & Chr(34) & olItem.Subject & Chr(34) & "," & _
                  Format(olItem.Start, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "," & _
                  Format(olItem.Start, "hh:mm AM/PM") & "," & _
                  Format(olItem.End, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "," & _
                  Format(olItem.End, "hh:mm AM/PM") & "," & _
                  Chr(34) & olItem.Location & Chr(34) & "," & _
                  Chr(34) & Replace(olItem.Body, vbCrLf, " ") & Chr(34) & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Next olItem
    
    ' Write to CSV file
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    fileNum = FreeFile
    Open csvFile For Output As #fileNum
    Print #fileNum, output
    Close #fileNum

    ' Notify user
    MsgBox "Calendar exported to " & csvFile, vbInformation, "Export Complete"

End Sub


olItems.IncludeRecurrences = True

That worked a treat... and I'm almost embarrassed it was that simple
